# Java: How to sort an ArrayList alphabetically with case insensitive and with any number Strings at the end

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I would like to sort my ArrayList alphabetically (case insensitive) but have any number Strings (e.g. "1999") be at the end of the list. Take the following code for example:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("abby");
names.add("Abigail");
names.add("Dylan");
names.add("becky");
names.add("011");
```

How would I get this to look like:

```
["abby", "Abigail", "becky", "Dylan", "011"]
```

I was going to use the following code:

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Although it sorts the number at the beginning of the ArrayList. Any ideas on what would be the easiest way to go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly not the easiest solution, but a flexible one is to use a [rules-based collator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html). An example - albeit for a different context - is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61015766/java-sort-a-list-of-objects-that-includes-a-special-character/61017926#61017926). One point for _number strings_: _Any_ string beginning with a digit will be sorted after _any_ string beginning with a letter. So, if you want "2foo" sorted before "1234", this would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composition

Create your own Comparator<String>. Test for digits first, then and use String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.

```
public class MyStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compareTo(String a, String b) {
    //if both a and b are digits, maybe use String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER?
    //if a is all digits return -1
    //if b is all digits return 1
    return String.CASE_INSENSTIVE_ORDER(a,b);
  }
}
```