# Sorting strings of letters, numbers, and special characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I have a list of strings that I would like to sort in a particular order.

The list is ["Bea", "hel", "Hel", "--'", "813", "!@#", "813", "813", "Alb"]

and I would like to have it sorted like:

[813, 813, 813, --', !@#, Alb, Bea, Hel, hel]

I have some code that gets pretty close but there is still one bug that I cannot figure out. Currently the program is producing this.

[813, 813, 813, Alb, --', !@#, Bea, Hel, hel]

Below is the code that I currently have

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;


class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bea", "hel", "Hel", "--'", "813", "!@#", "813", "813", "Alb");

    Collections.sort(list, STANDARD_ALPHABETICAL_ORDER);
    System.out.println(list);

  }


  public final static Comparator<String> STANDARD_ALPHABETICAL_ORDER =
    (a,b) -> {
        String newA = a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        String newB = b.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        int na = newA.length();
        int nb = newB.length();
        int r;
        int n;
        if (na < nb) {
            r = -1;
            n = na;
        } else if (na > nb) {
            r = -1;
            n = nb;
        } else {
            r = 0;
            n = na;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            char ca = newA.charAt(i);
            char cb = newB.charAt(i);
            if (ca != cb) {
                if (Character.isDigit(ca) && !Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                  return -1;
                } else if (!Character.isDigit(ca) && Character.isDigit(cb)) {
                  return 1;
                } else if (ca > cb ) {
                  return 1;
                } else {
                  return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return r;
    };
}
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your sorting criteria?

Comment: Sure, it's alphanumerically sorted. ignoring (but keeping) non-alphanumeric characters.with numbers preceding letters and with capital letters preceding lowercase letters (i.e., 0-9, A-Z, a-z)

Comment: I always save the data to a notebook text file and import the data into excel. Based on the way your data is displayed and assuming you do not want to included the ", I'd use delimited with the delimiter being " placed the the other box. Once imported you can save the file as an excel sheet and delete the unwanted columns and sort however you wish.

Comment: You can consider using a Java rules-based collator to define your own custom sort order. You can see an example (for a different custom sort order) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61017926/12567365).

Comment: I would create an object that has a String value and a sort value and on construction  generate the sort value from the String value, and srt those objects on their sort value. Your code will be cleaner and you'll keep your sanity.

Answer (score 0):

This part is buggy:

```
} else if (na > nb) {
    r = -1;
    n = nb;
```

Should be

```
} else if (na > nb) {
    r = 1;
    n = nb;
```

This would make appear  `--'` and `!@#` before all other values, because they will be the empty string when the replacement has been done for the  Variables `newA` or `newB`.  You have to change this, if it is not the intended result.